# Why is Search not working in Microsoft store app?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store

Search input field does not appear on screen when clicking the Search button in Microsoft Store app. Window 10 Home, version 1803.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the store and the search button will work.